# How to Equate dimensions of two tensors of sizes [64, 3, 128, 128] and [64, 64, 127, 127]

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, pytorch, tensor

I am trying to add two tensors of dimension `[64, 64, 127, 127]` and `[64, 3, 127, 127]` in pytorch, but I need to add zeros in the second tensor in order to equate their dimensions to `[64, 64, 127, 127]`.

I have tried adding zeros through slicing but it is not robust

Comment: What is your expected output? Do you want to add the second tensor to a specific subslice of length 3 of the first tensor? If so, which indices for dim=1 should they be added to?

Answer (score 0):

First one is easy to visualize:

```
import torch
zeros = torch.zeros(2, 2, 2, 10)
ones = torch.ones(2, 2, 2, 5)

zeros[:, :, :, :5] = ones
print(ones)
print(zeros)
```

Second one is what you need (zeros and ones is just for my test)

```
ones = torch.ones(64, 3, 127, 127)
zeros = torch.zeros(64, 61, 127, 127)
zeros[:, :3, :, :] = ones
```

OR using the `cat()` function simple as this:

```
torch.cat((ones, zeros), 1)
```